# UIAlertView clean up for background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, nsnotificationcenter

I read apple document about  [background mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) 
And I don't understand when should I dismiss my UIAlertView. In `applicationWillResignActive:` notification or in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`? And what the difference if I dismiss UIAlertView in `applicationWillResignActive:` or in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`?

Comment: the `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` is perfect to dismiss it, or you can use to clean up the `-viewDidDisappear:` method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have to* dismiss the alert view if your app goes into background. The `UIAlertView` documentation states:

> ... it is up to you to decide whether to dismiss the alert view (and
>   execute its cancellation handler) or leave it visible for when your
>   application moves back to the foreground.

But there are many cases where it makes sense to dismiss the alert view. If a user opens your app after 2 days and the first thing he sees is an alert "Do you really want to delete this file?" he will probably not know anymore what this question is about. For such a case it is better to dismiss the alert and cancel the corresponding action when the app goes into background.

I would use `applicationDidEnterBackground` (or the corresponding `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`) for this purpose, because `applicationWillResignActive` is also called for temporary interruptions such as incoming phone calls or SMS messages.